# Adding A For Loop And Printing JSON Key To A Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, html, json, for-loop, html-table

(The following script was created by a fellow colleague of mine named Kingizor from the DKC-Atlas Forums. Much kudos to him for helping create this script.)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
var json_data = [
{
    Name  : "Name 1",
    "Item1" : "Item 1a",
    "Item2" : "<i>Item 1b</i>",
    "Item3" : "Item 1c"
},
{
    Name  : "Name 2",
    "Item1" : "Item 2a",
    "Item2" : "<b>Item 2b</b>",
    "Item3" : "Item 2c"
},
{
    Name  : "Name 3",
    "Item1" : "Item 3a",
    "Item2" : "<s>Item 3b</s>",
    "Item3" : "Item 3c"
}
];

/* this function retrieves entry data and formats it for output */
function choose_item (el) {

    var output = document.getElementById("output");

    /* get the currently selected item */
    var entry = json_data[el.selectedIndex];

    /* remove the old contents */
    output.innerHTML = "";

    /* create three new item containers */
    var item1 = document.createElement("div");
    var item2 = document.createElement("div");
    var item3 = document.createElement("div");

    /* add the data to the items */
    item1.innerHTML = entry.Item1;
    item2.innerHTML = entry.Item2;
    item3.innerHTML = entry.Item3;

    /* add the items to the output */
    output.appendChild(item1);
    output.appendChild(item2);
    output.appendChild(item3);

}

/* this function creates the option elements for the select dropdown */
function setup () {

  var select = document.getElementById("select");

  /* generate the keys for the select dropdown */
  for (var key in json_data) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.innerHTML = json_data[key].Name;
      select.appendChild(option);
  }

  /* first item shown by default */
  choose_item(select);
}

/* execute the setup function when the page has finished loading */
window.addEventListener("load", setup)
```

**HTML**

```
<SELECT id="select" onchange="choose_item(this)"></SELECT>
<BR><BR>
<DIV id="output">You are seeing this message because you have JavaScript disabled!</DIV>
```

This is a JSON-engineered dynamic table-drop-down menu combo. When you open the page, you are greeted with a chart with many entries. The drop-down menu will consist of other names in the database that you can view by clicking on the drop-down and selecting that name. By doing so, you will load the entries that are from another JSON file (In this demonstration, they are referring to the json_data var storage; I would like to have them refer to a file instead). The name entry is nothing more than a value for the SELECT tag.

What I want to do is combine the var item, item.innerHTML, and `output.appendChild` statements into one `for`-loop, and I have no idea how to do this. Secondly, I want to turn the left columns into text that can be displayed. In the end, it should look like this:

**INTENDED RESULT**

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td>Item 1a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td>Item 1b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item3</td>
    <td>Item 1c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I read somewhere that you could use something like ${key} and ${value} in a Javascript for loop as a blanket wildcard, thinking it'd be useful, but then I'd be forced to use the backquotes. Is there a way that I can still use this without being forced to use backquotes?

Comment: you first should parse the JSON to a JS array of objects: `JSON.parse()`